# how to send json format as input and store in database in codeigniter rest for webservices

Tags: json, web-services, codeigniter

am using the following code for sending json format as input and to store it in db. when i decode the value am getting nothing. what was wrong in my code. can someone help me please.

controller

```
function join_community_post(){
        $serviceName = 'join_community';    
        //getting posted values
        $c =  '{"community" : [{"community_id":1},{"community_id":2},{"community_id":3}]}';
        $ip = trim($this->input->post($c));
        $ipJson = json_decode($ip);
        print_r ($ipJson);exit;
        $retVals = $this->user_model->user_join_community($ip, $serviceName);

        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo $retVals;
        exit;
    }
```

model

```
function user_join_community($ip,$serviceName) {
        $ipJson = json_decode($ip);
    }
```

Comment: shoudln't u be doing json_encode first then json_decode?

Comment: function $this->ville_lib->return_status() add the code for this function in your question...so that i can take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

The json_decode gives the stdClass Object if second parameter is not passed as true [PHP:json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

And second you are passing the post value of $c...check if its blank [Input Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html)

Controller

```
   function join_community_post(){
    $serviceName = 'join_community';    
    //getting posted values
    //$c =  '{"community" : [{"community_id":1},{"community_id":2},{"community_id":3}]}';
    $ip = trim($this->input->post($c));
    $ipJson = json_encode($ip);

    $retVals = $this->user_model->user_join_community($ip, $serviceName);

    header("content-type: application/json");
    echo $retVals;
    exit;
}
```

Model

```
 function user_join_community($c,$serviceName) {
         $ipJson = json_decode($c,true);
         $createArray = array();
         foreach($ipJson['community'] as $key=>$value){
           $createArray = array(
             'user_community_created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
             'user_community_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
             'community_id' => $value['community_id'] 
          );
      $insert = $this->db->insert('user_community', $createArray);
   }
   if ($insert) {
         $data['message'] = 'success';
         $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $c);
    } else {
        $data['message'] = 'Error';
         $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $c);
    }

  }
```

Removed semicolon after curly bracket of foreach and added the $c to the webservices table which was getting you the error.....hope it helps...

Comment: hi sonali,  function join_community_post(){
    $serviceName = 'join_community';    
    //getting posted values
    $c =  '{"community" : [{"community_id":1},{"community_id":2},{"community_id":3}]}';
    $ipJson = json_decode($c);
    print_r ($ipJson);exit;
    $retVals = $this->user_model->user_join_community($ip, $serviceName);

    header("content-type: application/json");
    echo $retVals;
    exit;
} i gave in this way removing $ip and the array is getting but how to pass this to model.

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [community] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [community_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [community_id] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [community_id] => 3
                )

        )

) am getting as above how to use foreach to store it in db

Comment: yeah i used that and it is working how to use foreach inorder to store these values in db can you suggest me please.

Comment: hi sonali i used as follow is this correct or wrong function user_join_community($c,$serviceName) {
  $ipJson = json_decode($c,true);
   if(is_array($ipJson['community']))
    {
        foreach($ipJson['community'] as $key=>$value)
  $insert = $this->db->insert('user_community', $key=>$value);
        echo $value['community_id']."<br>";
    }
  
 } but am getting the following error <br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\clamo\application\models\user_model.php</b> on line <b>88</b><br />

Comment: am having 5columns in user_community table community_id,user_id,community_user_id,created_time,modified_time. in this i have to store those values into community_id

Comment: i will be getting user_id, and modified date will be => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Comment: i didn't know exactly what header is header("content-type: application/json");

Comment: no am not able to insert am getting error when i used as i mentioned above

Comment: am getting the following error after using what you have edited <p>Error Number: 1054</p><p>Unknown column '1' in 'field list'</p><p>INSERT INTO `user_community` (`1`) VALUES ('')</p><p>Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\clamo\system\database\DB_driver.php</p><p>Line Number: 330</p> </div>

Comment: yeah i have tried in this way too $this->db->insert('user_community');
  $this->db->where('community_id', $value['community_id']); but am getting error as You must use the "set" method to update an entry.</p><p>Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\clamo\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Comment: hai sonali i have used in this way $createArray = array();
  foreach($ipJson['community'] as $key=>$value){
  $createArray = array(
   'user_community_created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'user_community_modified_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
   'community_id' => $value['community_id']
  );
  };
  $insert = $this->db->insert('user_community', $createArray); it is storing in db but only last value that is 3 is storing

Comment: hi sonali i have edited the code and also the issue iam facing above

Comment: changed the $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $c); line and $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $c); line...check again

Comment: still am facing same problem

Comment: you copied the code  right? dont pass $ipJson to the $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status(); its an array...pass $c its a string......

Comment: can you tell me the structure of the web_service_logs and also the function $this->ville_lib->return_status()..add it to your question dont add it in comment its difficult to read..

Comment: login,service,status,request and response